# Swift replace occurrence of string with condition

Tags: swift, swift-string

I have string like below

`<p><strong>I am a strongPerson</strong></p>`

I want to covert this string like this

`<p><strong>I am a weakPerson</strong></p>`

When I try below code

```
let old = "<p><strong>I am a strongPerson</strong></p>"
let new = old.replacingOccurrences(of: "strong", with: "weak")
print("\(new)")
```

I am getting output like

`<p><weak>I am a weakPerson</weak></p>`

But I need output like this

`<p><strong>I am a weakPerson</strong></p>`

My Condition here is

1.It has to replace only if word does not contain these HTML Tags like "<>".

Help me to get it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is easily with a regular expression

Comment: @Sh_Khan Can you please kindly help me to write Regular Expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to avoid the word being in a tag:

```
let old = "strong <p><strong>I am a strong person</strong></p> strong"
let new = old.replacingOccurrences(of: "strong(?!>)", with: "weak", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
print(new)
```

I added some extra uses of the word "strong" to test edge cases.

The trick is the use of `(?!>)` which basically means to ignore any match that has a `>` at the end of it. Look at the documentation for `NSRegularExpression` and find the documentation for the "negative look-ahead assertion".

Output:

> weak <p><strong>I am a weak person</strong></p> weak

Comment: I recommend that you also use a negative look-behind to avoid matching `"strong>"`, so the regular expression would then be `"(?<!<|<\/)strong(?!>)"`. A link to explain this is here: regexr.com/4g5o4

Comment: @Sam I was assuming you would never find `strong>` in the string because the `>` would be entered as `&gt;`.

Comment: @Sam It shows error for this string "\" , Invalid escape sequence in literal

Comment: In a Swift string you would need `"(?<!<|<\\/)string(?!>)"`. Note the double backslash.

Comment: @Manimurugan Exactly

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
let myString = "<p><strong>I am a strongPerson</strong></p>"
if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "strong(?!>)") {

 let modString = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: myString, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length:  myString.count), withTemplate: "weak")
  print(modString)
}
```

Comment: Why case insensitive?

Comment: In case of ``<p><strong>I am a StrongPerson</strong></p>``, As well as i have it in one of my file so he can omit it

Comment: But then `StrongPerson` becomes `weakPerson` and not `WeakPerson`. That may or may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: Thanks for your note, I'll omit it